# Firebase 9 и useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, firebase

Как мне сделать так что бы при изменении данных в базе данных на firestore срабатывал useEffect без постоянного цикла [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeKDl.png)

С 22 по 26 строку получаю данные с firestore и записываю их в useState на 27
Но когда с помощью input а добавляю новые значения в базу useEffect не срабатывает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно используете [условное срабатывание](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect.).
Ваша переменная `datee` никак не меняется, она всегда равна `db` (судя по всему, это объект firebase), хуку нет причин выполняться.

> Как мне сделать так что бы при изменении данных в базе данных на firestore срабатывал useEffect без постоянного цикла enter image description here

Вам нужно в useEffect подписаться на изменения, в `firebase/firestore`,  для получения обновлений в реальном времени, есть [необходимый метод onSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen). Используйте в связке с `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const unsub = onSnapshot(
  doc(db, "cities", "SF"), 
  (doc) => {
    // что-то сделать, подробности смотрите в документации firebase
  });

  return ()=>unsub()
}, [])
```

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался с вашей помощью